# How much replayability is there in Journey without multiplayer?

Tags: journey

I've never played Journey.  Apparently, it's extremely short (three hours or so front-to-back).  I also hear it's *wonderful*.

Here's the problem:  My PS3 is not (and will never be) connected to the internet.  This means that all my PS3 games are strictly single-player.  I don't want to buy it and discover that I've dropped a chunk of cash on a game where most of the enjoyment comes from playing over and over again with new people.

**How much replayability is there in Journey if multiplayer is not an option?**

Comment: How will you even _get_ the game if you're not connected to the internet? AFAIK the game is not available on physical media

Comment: @Alex - [Wikipedia claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_%282012_video_game%29) it's available on physical media, though this could be wrong.  If it's only available on PSN, then the question is meaningless.

Comment: Yep, looks like they bundled Flow, Flower and Journey together. My bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Journey certainly offers the beauty and gameplay that is expected of "That Game Company," it is extremely short. Your first playthrough will only take about an hour or two.

There is very limited replayability. While the game is unique, within several playthroughs, you will have completed the majority of trophies. Playing with others will allow several other trophy challenges, but the game presents a maximum of 10 hours of gameplay.

If you are attached to the idea of replayability, then Journey certainly isn't the right choice.